# JointJS how to create a HTML select (drop down) inside a shape object

Tags: svg, jointjs, rappid, foreignobject

I am looking for best practises or advice in how to create interactive elements within Shapes (elements) using the JointJS (Rappid) library.

This is what I have done currently:

[image]

The code

```
 const shape = new joint.shapes.basic.Generic({
        type: 'shape',
        attrs: {},
        markup: [
            {
                tagName: 'foreignObject',
                selector: 'foreignObject',
                attributes: {
                    x: '10',
                    y: '10',
                    width: '60',
                    height: '100',
                },
                children: [
                    {
                        tagName: 'div',
                        namespaceURI: 'http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml',
                        selector: 'content',
                        style: {
                            display: 'flex',
                            flexDirection: 'column',
                            alignItems: 'center',
                            justifyContent: 'center',
                        },

                        children: [
                            {
                                tagName: 'select',
                                selector: 'select',
                                style: {
                                    'z-index': 1,
                                },
                                children: [
                                    {
                                        tagName: 'option',
                                        value: 'test1',
                                        textContent: 'test 1',
                                    },
                                    {
                                        tagName: 'option',
                                        value: 'test2',
                                        textContent: 'test 2',
                                    },
                                ],
                            },
                        ],
                    },
                ],
            },
        ],
    });
```

You can see there is a shape rendered and it has a select element in it by using a `foreignObject` (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Element/foreignObject).
However, using `foreignObject` is  troublesome due to that they do not play well in browsers and the drop down you see here doesn't actually work.

I could start hacking around and get it to work but this is the point of the question, is there a cleaner way in achieving this?

I need something like this

https://resources.jointjs.com/tutorial/html-elements

But the html library is now decrepitated and JointJS wants you to use markup JSON instead.

Lastly, I have seen this post which doesn't fill me much with confidence...

https://groups.google.com/g/jointjs/c/-yXXlnreq6M

But I am hoping as this is from 5 years ago, it is outdated and we don't need to have to do the workarounds as it suggests?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HTML can be added inside `foreignObject`, but as you mentioned there can be some issues in browsers. One example of using foreignObject can be found [here.](https://github.com/clientIO/joint/blob/master/demo/shapes/src/foreign-object.js)

The code demonstrates how to create a text input with foreignObject.

```js
var paper = new joint.dia.Paper({
    el: document.getElementById('paper'),
    width: 650,
    height: 400,
    gridSize: 10,
    model: graph,
    guard: function(evt) {
        return evt.target instanceof HTMLInputElement;
    }
});

paper.on('blank:pointerdown cell:pointerdown', function() {
    document.activeElement.blur();
});

var Example = joint.dia.Element.define('example.ForeignObject', {
    attrs: {
        body: {
            refWidth: '100%',
            refHeight: '100%',
            stroke: '#333333',
            fill: '#ffffff',
            strokeWidth: 2
        },
        foreignObject: {
            refWidth: '100%',
            refHeight: '100%'
        }
    }
}, {
    markup: [{
        tagName: 'rect',
        selector: 'body'
    }, {
        tagName: 'foreignObject',
        selector: 'foreignObject',
        attributes: {
            'overflow': 'hidden'
        },
        children: [{
            tagName: 'div',
            namespaceURI: 'http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml',
            selector: 'content',
            style: {
                fontSize: 14,
                width: '100%',
                height: '100%',
                position: 'static',
                backgroundColor: 'transparent',
                textAlign: 'center',
                margin: 0,
                padding: '0px 10px',
                boxSizing: 'border-box',
                display: 'flex',
                flexDirection: 'column',
                alignItems: 'center',
                justifyContent: 'center'
            },
            children: [{
                tagName: 'span',
                textContent: 'First Name'
            }, {
                tagName: 'input',
                selector: 'firstname',
                attributes: {
                    'type': 'input',
                    'name': 'firstname'
                },
                style: {
                    position: 'static',
                    width: '100%'
                }
            }, {
                tagName: 'span',
                textContent: 'Last Name'
            }, {
                tagName: 'input',
                selector: 'lastname',
                attributes: {
                    'type': 'input',
                    'name': 'lastname'
                },
                style: {
                    position: 'static',
                    width: '100%'
                }
            }]
        }]
    }]
}, {
    attributes: {
        value: {
            set: function(text, _, node) {
                if ('value' in node) node.value = text;
            }
        }
    }
});

joint.shapes.example.ForeignObjectView = joint.dia.ElementView.extend({

    events: {
        'change input': 'onInputChange'
    },

    onInputChange: function(evt) {
        var input = evt.target;
        this.model.attr(input.name + '/value', input.value);
    }
});
```

The article that you linked is deprecated, but there is an updated version of creating elements with a HTML face [here](https://github.com/clientIO/joint/tree/master/demo/html). You can see some select fields demonstrated there, but it is a little more involved.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer James. Though I am reluctant to accept this as the answer, I think, for now, there is no other answer unfortunately. It seems combining SVG and HTML is hard work with JointJS+ and in general. Though through my research, using the d3 library seems slightly easier. Thanks again for the help!